# Visual Studio Setup project. Disable dependency detection for an individual file

Tags: c#, dependencies, project, installation

I have a setup project doing multiple things. One of those things is copying a few .NET Compact Framework DLL's and EXE's to a Win32 machine.

The setup project is automatically trying to detect the dependencies of these files which is resulting in some project warnings.

> Unable to find dependency 'SYSTEM' (Signature='969DB8053D3322AC'
>   Version='2.0.0.0') of assembly 'myassembly.exe"

Everything still works as it should, i just dont like warnings in my projects.

Comment: I've got the same thorn in my side. Everything works, but there's no reason why warnings should be left in the project. If it's okay for the compiler to always generate warnings there is no way to get rid of, it might as well remind you buy your wife a gift for your anniversary too while it's at it.